# First Order RL Circuit

Tags: passive-networks

In figure 8.21 $$ R_1 = 50 , R_2 = 200 , L = 2 H$$
Voltage is given by $$ V_{in}(t) = V_{s1}u(-t) + V_{s2}u(t) $$ where $$V_{S1} = -10 V , V_{S2} = 20 V$$

[image: Circuit Diagram]

a) Find  $$ I_L(0^+)  $$ and $$  I_L(t)$$ for t > 0

So far, I haven't done anything because I don't know what to do first. Some hints would appreciated.

Comment: What's the significance of the switch "S"? Are we supposed to assume that it opens at t=0? If so, you can ignore R2 altogether, since it never has any current going through it. If not, start by replacing the voltage source and the two resistors with their Thevenin equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Knowing that an inductor will initially behave as an [open][short](pick one) circuit  will answer the behavior at t=0+.
2. Knowing how the inductor behaves at t = infinity will let you find the asymptotic value of I<sub>L</sub>.
3. Figuring out the time constant of the circuit will let you fill in the time in between.

Comment: At t=0 the inductor will behave as an open circuit.
and just wondering , what about at t=0- (t 0*minus)  how does it differ from t 0*plus

Comment: The main thing you need to know is, the current through an inductor will never change instantly. Similarly, but not relevant to this problem, the voltage across a capacitor will never change instantly.